# Calculating eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am dealing with a task in which I have to calculate the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the following matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
5& 6 &1\\
1 &3& 1\\
2 &1 &2\end{pmatrix}$$

So I have computed the characteristic equation, which turns out to be this three-degree polynomial:

$$-λ^3+10\lambda^2 -22\lambda +20$$

This cannot be factored by Ruffini, which leaves me stuck as to finding the roots I need. Have I done something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't there a typo in the matrix?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that the characteristic polynomial should have "nice" roots (e.g. at least one rational)? If so, you may want to recheck the matrix entries.

Comment: Yes, I think it should. We haven't studied any fancy or complex methods: only simple examples where the characteristic polynomial generated a quadratic or a third degree equation that you could factor. The matrix comes from a polynomial equation I worked with in previous exercises: 5x+6y+z = 2, x+3y+z=0 and 2x+y+2z=2

Comment: Perhaps the top row should be 5 6 5?

Comment: Maybe the exercise has a typo?

Comment: You will get a solution but not an elegant one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python code

```
from sympy import pprint
from sympy.printing.latex import LatexPrinter, print_latex
from sympy.matrices import  Matrix

A = Matrix([[5,6,1],[1,3,1],[2,1,2]])
pprint( A )
E = A.eigenvals()
print_latex( E )
```

produces
\begin{align}
\lambda_1&=\frac{10}{3} + \left(- \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3} i}{2}\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{2 \sqrt{1086}}{9} + \frac{280}{27}} + \frac{34}{9 \left(- \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3} i}{2}\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{2 \sqrt{1086}}{9} + \frac{280}{27}}}\,,\\ 
\lambda_2&=\frac{10}{3} + \frac{34}{9 \left(- \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3} i}{2}\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{2 \sqrt{1086}}{9} + \frac{280}{27}}} + \left(- \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3} i}{2}\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{2 \sqrt{1086}}{9} + \frac{280}{27}}\,,\\ 
\lambda_3&=\frac{34}{9 \sqrt[3]{\frac{2 \sqrt{1086}}{9} + \frac{280}{27}}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{2 \sqrt{1086}}{9} + \frac{280}{27}} + \frac{10}{3}\,.
\end{align}

To wrap up some comments:

The numerical values of the eigenvectors are
\begin{align}
\lambda_1&\approx 1.30555781-\mathbf{i}\,1.00114303\,,\\
\lambda_2&\approx 1.30555781+\mathbf{i}\,1.00114303\,,\\
\lambda_3&\approx 7.38888438\,.  
\end{align}
As pointed out by ancient mathematician, all three eigenvectors can be obtained from
$$
\begin{pmatrix}5-\lambda\\6\\1\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}1\\3-\lambda\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3+\lambda\\-4+\lambda\\\lambda^2-8\lambda+9\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
The only thing that is not immediately obvious is that
the dot product of this vector with $(2,1,2-\lambda)$ (the last row of $A-\lambda I$) is zero. This dot product is however equal to the characteristic polynomial
$$
- \lambda^3+ 10 \lambda^2 - 22 \lambda +20
$$
and therefore zero when $\lambda$ is one of the eigenvalues.

Another tip:

In that case, the exact expressions above for the eigenvalues produced by `sympy` are impressive but practically nearly useless because too complicated. If you only want the numerical values use `scipy.linalg`:

```
from numpy import array
from scipy.linalg import eig
A = array([[5,6,1],[1,3,1],[2,1,2]])
E, V = eig(A)
```

Comment: And of course the corresponding eigenvectors are $(\lambda_i^2-8\lambda_i+9,3+\lambda_1, -4+\lambda_i)$. ;=)

Comment: @ancientmathematician I checked numerically that this does not quite seem the case.

Comment: Surely $(5-\lambda_i, 6, 1) \times (1, 3-\lambda_i, 1)$ is an eigenvector. It is killed by each row of $A-\lambda_i$

Comment: @ancientmathematician I can see that for the first two rows of $A-\lambda$ but since
$$
\begin{pmatrix}5-\lambda\\6\\1\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}1\\3-\lambda\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3+\lambda\\-4+\lambda\\\lambda^2-8\lambda+9\end{pmatrix}
$$
I get that the dot product of this with $(1,2,1-\lambda)$ is
$$
-\lambda^3+9\lambda^2-14\lambda+4\,.
$$

Comment: Kurt, we have both made a slip. Me by messing up what the cross product is, sorry; you I think by dotting with $(1,2,1-\lambda)$ [column] instead of with $(2,1,2-\lambda)$ [row].

Comment: @ancientmathematician I made a slip but you did not. The correct dot product with the last row is $$ - \lambda^3+ 10 \lambda^2 - 22 \lambda +20$$ which is the characteristic polynomial and therefore zero. Nice!

Comment: Thanks. I think the teacher must have made a slip in assigning this task, because  we haven't seen or used all this heavy machinery yet. We are supposed to just be able to decompose the characteristic polynomial 'easily' and haven't been taught or instructed to use code or numerical approximation.

Comment: @ManuelDelRíoRodríguez Sure. I do however promote that little python code wherever I can because it will hopefully help in the future to self-check your stuff regardless what mistake the teacher made.