# Find the eigenvectors , generalized eigenvectors and the minimal polynomial of a certain matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

> Given $A=$ $
> \begin{pmatrix}
> -3 & 1 &-1 \\
> -7 & 5 & -1 \\
> -6 & 6 & -2 \\
> \end{pmatrix}
> $
> and also the characteristic polynomial $P_A(x)=(x+2)^2 \cdot (x-4)$
>
> 1. Find the eigenvectors , generalized eigenvectors and the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $A$ diagonalizable ?
> 2. let $T: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ be $Tv=Av$ find $[T]_B$ $B$ is the given basis of $\Bbb R^3$ >from the generalized eigenvectors

---

I started by finding the minimal polynomial and it is the same as $P_A$ this is because $A$ is not a scalar matrix and $P_A$ does not factor (sorry if the translation is incorrect hopefully it is understandable)

now I checked the eigenvectors to check if it is diagonalizable according to their geometric and algebraic multiplicity and got
$(A-4I)=$ $
\begin{pmatrix}
-7 & 1 &-1 \\
-7 & 1 & -1 \\
-6 & 6 & 6 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$
from here the null space is $span\{v_1=$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
1  \\
\end{pmatrix}\}$

$(A+2I)=$ $
\begin{pmatrix}
-7 & 1 &-1 \\
-7 & 1 & -1 \\
-6 & 6 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$ and the same from here the null space is $span\{v_2=$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
-1 \\
0  \\
\end{pmatrix}\}$

from here we can see it is not diagonalizable

the generalized eigenvector: $(A+2I)^2=$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0& 0 &0 \\
-36 & 36 & 0 \\
36 & -36 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

as before the null space is $span\{v_2=$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
-1 \\
0  \\
\end{pmatrix}$ $v_2=$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1  \\
\end{pmatrix}\}$

for the second part our basis is $B=\{v_2,v_3,v_1\}$ but how do I continue from here ? how can I find $[T]_B$?

Thanks for any help and tips

EDIT-

My main question is part two, not on how to calculate eigenvectors and eigenvalues

I also tried $Tv_2=-2v_2=-2v_2+0v_3+0v_1$ where $-2$ is from the eigenvalue and $Tv_1=4v_1=0v_3+0v_2+4v_1$ for the same reasno but I got stuck at $Tv_3=Av_3$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a 3x3 matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4740799/calculating-eigenvectors-and-eigenvalues-of-a-3x3-matrix)

Comment: @KurtG. thank you but not really, I calculated the eigenvectors (eigenvalues are given from the characteristic polynomial) my problem is what I asked in the last line

Comment: I am promoting the `sympy` program mainly for the reason that OPs self-check their eigenvalues and eigenvectors. If you can boil down the question so something `sympy` cannot solve we can reconvene.

Comment: @KurtG. I am sorry I do not understand what you mean

Comment: Let $B=(A-\lambda_2 I)$, we know $Bv_2=0$ and the generalized eigenvector $v_3$ is obtained as $Bv_3=v_2$. Let $S=[v_1, v_2, v_3]$, we get $S^{-1}AS=J$ where $J$ is a matrix in the Jordan form.

Comment: What is $[T]_B$? The matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $B$?

Comment: @KurtG. This question is about a non-diagonalizable $3\times3$ matrix. I fail to see and the answer to the question that you mentioned can possibly help the OP to find an answer to their question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I gave to that OP the following comment today after which he deleted the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745688/question-about-representation-matrices). "It is well known that the columns of any matrix are the images of the canonical basis vectors. What does this tell us about matrix representation of a linear map? If you want another basis remember what you have learned how matrices transform when the basis is changed." The normal reaction should have been to discuss this until it is understood.

Comment: @KurtG. thanks for the help, I am obviously trying to understand this concept and not going so well therefore I try to ask here after trying and showing my ways.. 
I know the definitions but struggling to actually use them

Comment: In that case I am particularly pissed off because it is tedious to dig out a post that was deleted instead of being developed into something fruitful.

Comment: @KurtG. I deleted the other one because I managed to understand what happened there, it was because of the projection matrix

Anyway I would rather not discuss this on this post, thank you for the help!

Comment: If that happens you should do the following: answer the question yourself. Others might learn from it. MSE is not a personal homework service.

Comment: @KurtG. Never used this site for homework. obviously I always post my ways and if it is from a textbook with solutions I always post the solution as well ( as I did on the deleted post you can recheck that I posted the book solution)

Comment: If you don't contribute to MSE in the way I suggested I will in the future ignore your posts. Have a nice day.

Comment: @KurtG. again, I do not mean anything in a disrespectful way but you can recheck my post that it has a solution, never have I used this site for someone to solve my questions ( obviously 95% of what I post already has a solution from books) but I want to understand more or try new ways..

Comment: How about this gem (from the deleted post) ? "I remember it being a "technical" algorithm but I cannot seem to remember it" . I luv it .

Comment: @KurtG. Yes because this is how I remember representation matrices I remember it being a technical way (hopefully this is the right word) 

anyway this is the last time I will answer you , thanks for the help never expected a post here to turn childish.

Comment: A downvote is unnecessary here, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B=(A-\lambda_2 I)$, we know $Bv_2=0$ and the generalized eigenvector $v_3$ is obtained as $Bv_3=v_2$. Let $S=[v_1, v_2, v_3]$, we get $S^{-1}AS=J$ where $J$ is a matrix in the Jordan form.

In details, we start with $Bv_3=v_2$, we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix} -1& 1&-1&-1 \\ -7& 7& -1&-1\\ -6& 6& 0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
The reduced row echelon form of the above augmented matrix is

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1& -1&0&0 \\ 0& 0& 1&1\\ 0& 0& 0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$

From the above, we have the following equations
$$
\begin{align}
x_1 - x_2 &= 0, \\
x_3 = 1.
\end{align}
$$

Let $x_2=t$, we get $x_1=t,x_3=1$, the generalized vector is $v_3=[1,1,1]^T$ (i.e. not unique). Let $S=[v_1,v_2,v_3]$, we get

$$
S^{-1}AS= \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 4& 0&0 \\ 0& -2& 1\\ 0& 0& -2\end{bmatrix}}_{J}.
$$